# C# - Query Multiple Comma Delimited Value Search Parameters w/ String Splitter

Tags: c#, multithreading, csv, query-string

**Requirement:** I have a windows application written in C# that currently will only search a .CSV file by 1 Corp value (ex: Search by Corp: 160) and I want it to search multiple Corp values seperated by commas (ex: Search by Corp: 160, 220, 310, 550, 610).

**Problem:** How do I search multiple corp values seperated by commas?? 
(ex: Search by Corp: 160, 220, 310, 550, 610). 
The string has to be split by the comma value and the value of each string must be set to x+1 # of variables (ex: Corp1, Corp2, Corp3) when there are x # of commas (ex: Corp1, Corp2, Corp3 has 2 commas so 3 variables would have to be defined) and then looping the search x+1 times for each of the corp values

Here is the relevant code in **MainForm.cs** code where the corp value is defined:

```
    private SearchCriteria GetSearchCriteria()
    {

        // Initialize Search Parameters object
        SearchCriteria sc = new SearchCriteria(textBoxCorp.Text,
                                               textBoxOrderNumber.Text,
                                               textBoxCampaign.Text,
                                               textBoxCity.Text,
                                               comboBoxState.Text,
                                               textBoxZip.Text,
                                               folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,
                                               folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath,
                                               radioButtonAny.Checked,
                                               radioButtonAll.Checked);

        return sc;
    }

    private void textBoxCorp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Here is the relevant code in **SearchProcess.cs** where the corp value is brought in and checked to see if it matches the search:

```
    // Function runs in worker thread and emulates long process.
    public void Run()
    {
        m_sc = (SearchCriteria)m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateGetSearchCriteria);
        // Display parameters
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on Corp: " + m_sc.get_Corp() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on OrderNumber: " + m_sc.get_OrderNumber() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on Campaign: " + m_sc.get_Campaign() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on City: " + m_sc.get_City() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on State: " + m_sc.get_State() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on Zip: " + m_sc.get_Zip() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on Source Path: " + m_sc.get_SourcePath() });
        m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search on Target Path: " + m_sc.get_TargetPath() });
        if (m_sc.get_SearchAND()==true)
        {
            m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search for All" });
        }
        else
        {
            m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] { "Search for Any" });
        }

            // Found should be true if ANY of the criteria are met. 
            // This is an OR logic gate
            // If any of the given fields do match then it is a true
            if (m_sc.get_SearchOR().Equals(true))
            {
                // Check for the Corp type match
                if (m_sc.get_Corp() != "" && String.Compare(AgentID, m_sc.get_Corp()) == 0)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
        }

            // Copy the file if ANY of the search criteria have been met
            if (found)
            {

                m_form.Invoke(m_form.m_DelegateAddString, new Object[] {"FOUND: Order_No: " + Order_No +
                                                                        " barcode: " + barcode +
                                                                        " MailerCode: " + MailerCode +
                                                                        " AgentID: " + AgentID +
                                                                        " City: " + City +
                                                                        " State: " + State +
                                                                        " ZIP: " + ZIP});
                //passes values to TransferFile 
                TransferFile(directory, barcode, AgentID, ZIP);
            }
        } // end for that finds each matching record
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Can anyone answer this question??

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you are doing, where is the data source you make the search on, so just guessing:

```
string sCorpFilter = m_sc.get_Corp();
IEnumerable<string> corps = null;

if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(sCorpFilter))
{
  corps = sCorpFilter.Split(",".ToCharArray(),
   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Trim());
}
[...]
if (corps != null && corps.Contains(AgentID))
{
  found = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The datasource is a csv file that does not have Totals in the name which is called in the evaluateCSVfile method- if (!f.Contains("TOTALS")) evaluateCSVfile(d, f); DataTable table = CSVReader.ReadCSVFile(qualifiedFileName, true). what is the code missing in the [...]  section?

Comment: what about setting the value of each string to x+1 # of variables (ex: Corp1, Corp2, Corp3) when there are x # of commas (ex: Corp1, Copr2, Corp3 has 2 commas so 3 variables would have to be defined) and then looing the saerch x+1 times for each x+1 # of corp values.

Comment: @Brian: you can dismiss the `[...]` section, that's only to indicate that you should initialize/sanitize your filter data somewhere in the beginning of your method, for readability and reusability reasons. For the second point, assuming that users can input from 0 to X Corps, you aren't going to create an arbitrary number of variables each representing a Corp, aren't you? A variable-length list of strings (means, its length can vary from 0 to the theoretical infinity) is best suited here.